# Why doesn't my freenet.de email account open under Tor?

Tags: email

I can open www.freenet.de under Tor, but if I want to log into my email account, it is rejected under Tor. What can I do? Freenet says that I should delete all cookies and browsing history. I did that, but even no access.

Answer (score 1):

That often happens when NoScript is not allowing the scripts the site needs to log you in. To you it will appear that you have entered your username and password, but the data is not sent to the site. Click on the NoScript icon and temporarily allow all on the page or set the options to allow you to control individual scripts. 
(Which is more difficult because sites often require lots of other sites to work, I had to allow 5 other sites to make this page work, and one of them contained the name Google (which is the enemy of everything Tor stands for in my opinion)).